# Plotting different lines for different groups of rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

How can I use pandas with the plotly backend to generate one single time-series graph containing two lines, one for Ankit and one for John?

Here's the code that generates the dataframe in the screenshot:

```
import pandas
pandas.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

details = { 
    'Name' : ['Ankit', 'John', 'Ankit', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Ankit', 'Ankit'], 
    'Month': ['January', 'January', 'February', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'March', 'April'],
    'Grade' : [9, 8, 7, 10, 8, 9, 8, 10], 
} 
d = pandas.DataFrame(details)
d = d.groupby(['Name', 'Month'], as_index=False)['Grade'].mean()
print(d)
```

If I just do:

```
d.plot(x='Month', y='Grade')
```

that would produce one single line not distinguishing between Ankit and John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code change order in `groupby` and aggregate `mean` with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
d = pandas.DataFrame(details)
df = d.groupby(['Month','Name'])['Grade'].mean().unstack()

df.plot()
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
d = pandas.DataFrame(details)
df = d.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Name', values='Grade', aggfunc='mean')

df.plot()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = d.pivot(index='Month', columns='Name', values='Grade')
d.plot()
```